# Tabs are not copied to R terminal.

Tags: r, terminal

When I copy some cells from spreadsheet (libreoffice in Linux) and paste it in text editor (I am using Geany), different cell entries are separated by tabs:

```
col1    col2    col3
first   1   a
second  2   b
third   3   c
```

I modify it in the text editor as follows:

```
mydf = read.table(header=T, text="
col1    col2    col3
first   1   a
second  2   b
third   3   c
")
```

However, when I copy from text editor to R terminal, the tabs are not copied and different cell entries are fused together as one string:

```
> mydf = read.table(header=T, sep='\t', text="
+ col1col2col3
+ first1a
+ second2b
+ third3c
+ ")

> mydf
  col1col2col3
1      first1a
2     second2b
3      third3c
>
```

The same occurs when I use leafpad text editor. Only copying to terminal creates this problem. Copying from one text editor to another is OK.

How can I correct this? What is the best method to copy data with tabs from text editor R?

Comment: Why not save as file and then read the file?

Comment: Copying & saving takes time and creates unnecessary files if short pieces of data are to be tested. Any solution to problem of copying & pasting tabs in terminal?

Comment: How about `read.delim("clipboard")` or `read.table(text = readClipboard(), sep="\t", header=TRUE)`?

Comment: You avoid this problem and gain a whole lot of other advantages if you use an IDE (such as RStudio).

Comment: @zx8754: read.table(text = readClipboard(), sep="\t", header=TRUE)   works and directly pastes from spreadsheet. The read.delim("clipboard") command works only if text is copied from a text editor but not if it copied from a spreadsheet. If you enter your response as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
read.delim("clipboard")
```

or

```
read.table(text = readClipboard(), sep="\t", header=TRUE)
```